# Breaking Case with certain responses

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

I am creating a little scoring program and am having trouble with this case. When I enter an 'e', it breaks correctly as the default suggests, but then it runs through the first switch statement, and then exits the program..

This only happens when I enter the letter 'e'. If i enter 'q' or anything else, it doesnt exit ?

```
case 'd': // Field Competition Logs
{
  int fieldRound;

  int ifaaField[2], ifaaFieldTotal;
  int ifaaHunter[2], ifaaHunterTotal;
  int fitaField[1];
  int field3D[1];

  printf ("Please select the type of round you shot\n\n");
  printf ("\t(a) IFAA Field\n\t(b) IFAA Hunter\n\t(c) Fita Field\n\t(d) 3D Field\n> ");
  scanf (" %d", &fieldRound);

  switch (fieldRound)
  {
    case 'a': // Ifaa Field Round
    {
      printf ("Please enter the score for your first round > ");
      scanf (" %d", &ifaaField[0]);

      printf ("Please enter the score for your second round > ");
      scanf (" %d", &ifaaField[1]);

      ifaaFieldTotal = ifaaField[0] + ifaaField[1];

      printf ("Total of your first half (%d) and your second half (%d) is %d", ifaaField[0], ifaaField[1], ifaaFieldTotal);

      break;
    }

    case 'b': // Ifaa Hunter Round
    {
      printf ("Please enter the score for your first round > ");
      scanf (" %d", &ifaaHunter[0]);

      printf ("Please enter the score for your second round > ");
      scanf (" %d", &ifaaHunter[1]);

      ifaaHunterTotal = ifaaHunter[0] + ifaaHunter[1];

      printf ("Total of your first half (%d) and your second half (%d) is %d", ifaaHunter[0], ifaaHunter[1], ifaaHunterTotal);

      break;
    }

    case 'c': // Fita Field Round
    {
      printf ("Please enter your Fita Field score > ");
      scanf (" %d", &fitaField[0]);

      printf ("Total of your Fita Field round is %d", fitaField[0]);

      break;
    }

    case 'd': // Field 3D Round
    {
      printf ("Please enter your 3D Field score > ");
      scanf (" %d", &field3D[0]);

      printf ("Total of your 3D Field round is %d", field3D[0]);

      break;
    }

    default:
    printf ("Please enter a valid response");
    break;
  }

  break; // Breaks out of Case D

}

case 'e': // Exits the program
{
  printf ("Thank you, Good bye!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Please select the type of round you shot

    (a) IFAA Field
    (b) IFAA Hunter
    (c) Fita Field
    (d) 3D Field
> e
Please enter a valid response
Hi s. c, Please choose from the following options by typing the letter and pressing the 'return' key

    (a) Enter Scored Practice logs
    (b) Enter Practice Arrow count
    (c) Enter Competition logs
    (d) Enter Field Competition Logs
    (e) Exit Program
> Thank you, Good bye!
```

Comment: In inner `switch` you read character by this `scanf (" %d", &fieldRound);` in `int variable` , you know that won't work .

Comment: AH ! AmeyCU Thank you!! I have been writing so many int today I didnt even realise it should be a char ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        scanf (" %d", &fieldRound);
```

This `scanf` fails! It expects numeric input, not an alphabetic character!

Comment: Thanks Klas, In the comments above I was reminded of this too! Spend all day writing tons of Integers I blanked on writing this as one too! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
        scanf (" %d", &fieldRound);
```

to

```
        scanf (" %c", &fieldRound);
```

In your current configuration, your scanf expects a decimal number, not a character. It thusly fails if you try inputting a character.

Additionally, you need to change `int fieldRound;`  to `char fieldRound;`.

Comment: Not just this ,also variable declaration to char.

Comment: @wrangler just noticed, I changed it.